# amazon web services - how to get all alarms except autoscaling?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch, cloudwatch-alarms

I want to use python's boto3 library to get all open alarms that aren`t related to autoscaling. So, basically, all alarms that you see, when you click "Hide Auto Scaling alarms" in Cloudwatch.

Comment: You need a custom solution for this for sure. As the doc says: "When you view your alarms in the AWS Management Console, you can hide the alarms related to Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling. This feature is available only in the AWS Management Console". If you can name all your alarms in two ways(prefixes) e.g autoscaling and "others" you can use `AlarmNamePrefix` and get only "others".

Comment: I`ve noticed that autoscaling alarm have alarm action that begins with "aws:arn:autoscaling", so I think I can use in conjuction with action-prefix property, but thanks nonetheless